# Question on how to call a function defined in a class in python

Tags: python-3.x, function, class

I'm trying to understand how classes and `self` work. I now have the following code that has one class and functions defined in it.

```
from typing import Dict, Any


class LearnClasses:
    def checks(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        return {
            **self.chk1(),
            **self.chk2(),
            **self.chk3(),
        }

    def chk1(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:

        chk_id = self.chk1.__name__

        return {
            f'{chk_id}': "Is"
        }

    def chk2(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:

        chk_id = self.chk1.__name__

        return {
            f'{chk_id}': "it"
        }

    def chk3(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:

        chk_id = self.chk3.__name__

        return {
            f'{chk_id}': "working?"
        }
```

Could someone explain how to call the function `checks` in `LearnClass`?

I tried `LearnClasses.checks()` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to call normal methods in a class, you need to create an instance of the class. Then you call the method on the instance:

```
instance = LearnClasses()
instance.checks()
```

Note that the code you have now doesn't make a whole lot of sense. The usual purpose of a class is to store some data along side methods that operate on it. Your `LearnClasses` class doesn't have any data to store or operate on, so it's not very useful.

A slightly more illustrative example might be:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def info(self):
        return f"{self.name} is {self.age} years old"
```

You'd create the instance by calling the class, which invokes the `__init__` method to store the data we have for the person. The `info` method does something useful with that data, producing a string:

```
joe = Person("Joe", 39)
print(joe.info())              # prints "Joe is 39 years old"
```